# Production server turns 10.00 into 1000

Tags: asp.net, iis, decimal

I have a .net application running locally on my machine. When run on my machine, it displays my prices as intended (example: $10.00), however as soon as I copy the application onto my server, it returns the same price as $1000.

The service returning the prices is the exact same. It returns a decimal, and the view prefixes it with a dollar sign.

Do you have any idea on why the decimal is removed on my server, but not on my local machine?

Comment: I think we had something similar once. The Problem was, that the was in us notation and locallly we had german. So the . was interpreted differently. This is, for example, is the bad side of .toString() ;) are those two machines in different languages?

Comment: Seems like something else; 10 != 1000.

Comment: To me it seems like the decimal (the dot itself) is removed somehow.
Yes @Simons0n they are different languages, but I checked currency format in windows itself and globalization settings in the IIS, and those are the same on both machines.
The Web.config also includes a culture